# How to import node.js child_process to Ember Electron app?

Tags: ember.js, electron

I'm trying to convert a node.js app to Ember Electron app. In the node.js app I use:

`const spawn = require('child_process').spawnSync;`

but don't know how to import 'child_process' into Ember Electron app.
Have tried:

`import { child_process } from 'child_process'; // blows up: requireNode is not a function`

and also:

```
import requireModule from 'ember-require-module'; 
const child_process = requireModule('child_process'); // does not find it
```

Maybe using node.js is a wrong approach in Ember Electron app?
Any idea appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the documentation says how to do it:

const spawn = requireNode('child_process').spawnSync;

https://ember-electron.js.org/docs/guides/development-and-debugging#require-and-requirenode-

And it works perfect.